# Apache serve alternate file extension for javascript?

Tags: apache-2.2

If the client requests a file ending with `.js` from Apache, I'd like Apache to first check if there is a `.js.min` file of the same basename and serve it if it exists, and otherwise, serve the original `.js` file. Can I do that with the standard Apache mods that come with Debian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Absolutely.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.min -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.min [T=text/javascript]
```

You may want the `L` flag as well, if you know you don't need further rewriting.

Comment: Cool. I was thinking MultiViews would be used for something like this. BTW, I think you meant to put parens around your match, like `RewriteRule (.*) $1.min`.

Comment: Indeed I did. Fixed.